# pgfplots yticklabels wont work

Tags: pgfplots

I have this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={unipdf(\x,\xl,\xu)= (\x>\xl)*(\x<\xu)*1/(\xu-\xl);}]
    \begin{axis}[
        samples=100,
        const plot mark mid,
        scaled ticks = false,
        ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
        xmin=-3,xmax=3,
        xtick={-2,2},
        xticklabels={-$\frac{LSB}{2}$,$\frac{LSB}{2}$}],
        ytick={0.25},
        yticklabels={$\frac{1}{LSB}$}]
        \addplot [very thick, orange] {unipdf(x,-2,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now this works all fine except that the y-label is not positioned correctly (always at 0) and that there is several other y-ticks:

[image: error probability density function]

Is there a particular reason for this behavior or is it just a bug?

I use the following packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: You have an extra `]` after the `xticklabels`, so the options regarding the yticks are not considered.

Comment: ohwow thank you very much! It didn't complain about the syntax so I would have never thought that there could be a syntax related issue :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torbjørn T. answered this pretty quick:

> You have an extra ] after the xticklabels, so the options regarding the yticks are not considered.

Sadly pdflatex didn't complain about that issue so I would have never suspected a syntax issue ...