# pgfplots boundingbox is offset

Tags: pgfplots

So I got this code to visualize the bounding boxes in my tex:

```
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={unipdf(\x,\xl,\xu)= (\x>\xl)*(\x<\xu)*1/(\xu-\xl);}]
            \begin{axis}[
                samples=100,
                const plot mark mid,
                scaled ticks = false,
                ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
                xmin=-3,xmax=3,
                xtick={-2,2},
                xticklabels={-$\frac{LSB}{2}$,$\frac{LSB}{2}$}],
                ytick={0.25},
                yticklabels={$\frac{1}{LSB}$}]
                \addplot [very thick, orange] {unipdf(x,-2,2)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \caption{$dt=0.1$}
        \label{fig:prob1_6_2}
    \end{minipage}%
    }
```

Which results in this:

[image: weird bounding boxes]

Of course, fbox could be wrong. Sadly the borders confirm what I suspected: The bounding boxes have a weird offset. So having the minipage at 0.5\linewidth lets the plots overlap.

I would be glad if someone points out to me where my missconception lies since I cannot find a particular reason for this.

Comment: You haven't fixed the bug in your code that I mentioned in your previous question ...

Comment: No indeed, in this picture I didn't, you are absolutely right. It has no influence tho (I can show you if you like so).

Comment: Yes it does have an influence on the result (though I'm not entirely sure why), try the code in my answer with and without that extra `]`.

Comment: thank you very much kind sir! Why I said it doesn't matter is because I already corrected it and just posted the answer before (don't ask why). But it didn't change anything. The width attribute on the axis fixed it tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. [pgfplots yticklabels wont work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355218/pgfplots-yticklabels-wont-work)
2. The default width of an `axis` is 240pt, but with a standard `article` document, `0.5\columnwidth` is 172.5pt. Hence, the `axis` is wider than the `minipage`, and thus sticks out on the right side. Add e.g. `width=\textwidth` to the `axis` options.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\the\columnwidth
\begin{figure}
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={unipdf(\x,\xl,\xu)= (\x>\xl)*(\x<\xu)*1/(\xu-\xl);}]
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\textwidth,
                samples=100,
                const plot mark mid,
                scaled ticks = false,
                ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
                xmin=-3,xmax=3,
                xtick={-2,2},
                xticklabels={-$\frac{LSB}{2}$,$\frac{LSB}{2}$},
                ytick={0.25},
                yticklabels={$\frac{1}{LSB}$}]
                \addplot [very thick, orange] {unipdf(x,-2,2)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \caption{$dt=0.1$}
        \label{fig:prob1_6_2}
    \end{minipage}%
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]